# Swift - Saving images as bitmap

Tags: ios, image, swift, bitmap, byte

I am trying to save an image as a bitmap using AVFoundation. Right now I am using jpeg, and was wondering what I would need to change in order to save the image as a bitmap. Side note - we plan on storing the byte[] onto our google app engine and then any device (Android or IOS) that would need the image, would be able to pull the byte[] from the database and convert it into an image on the device. Is this a valid way of going about storing images? If not what would you suggest?

Here is my code saving the image as a jpeg

```
@IBAction func didPressTakePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                var dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                var cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)

                //change orientation based on if the camera is front or back

                if self.selectedCamera == 1 {
                    var image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored)
                    self.capturedImage.image = image
                } else {
                    var image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation:UIImageOrientation.Right)
                    self.capturedImage.image = image
                }
```

Comment: A jpeg image IS a bit map image, so what are you asking exactly. How to save it to a file?

Comment: Ok so how do I get the byte[] itself?

Comment: var imageData is your byte array :-)

Comment: Ahh thanks :D. Do you have any knowledge on how to send the byte array to a google app engine database? Would I do that in my xcode project or would I write that code somewhere on the server?